# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '='

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a check in power shell to see if a file exists, and if so copy it to another location and if other wise just print an error message to the screen.

```
if (Test-Path "Z:\Network Folder\Another Folder\"FileInQuestion.docx") {
    Write-Host "Contents exist and and will be copied!"
} else {
    Write-Host "ERROR: Cannot find file."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for what I replyed last time,I didn't see carefully

Try this `test-path "\\network folder\another folder\YourFiles.docx"`
Usually,We don't use `z:\`,unless it is a real path. You said it is a network path.

`\"FileInQuestion.docx"` there is more `"` in that path

Had you ever used `Net-Use` command before you used `test-path`?

Comment: How do you mean, if I can't copy directly from the network drive what will I have to put in instead?